# Ejecutar script python desde VB.NET(IronPython)

Tags: python, vb.net

Tengo el siguiente código en VB.NET, y funciona...

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Hosting

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim pyEngine As ScriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine()
        Dim scope As ScriptScope = pyEngine.CreateScope()

        pyEngine.ExecuteFile("prueba.py", scope)

        Dim workingMethod As Object = scope.GetVariable("saludar")
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim result As Object = workingMethod("Patricio")
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        MsgBox(result, vbInformation, "Prueba Vb.Net/Python") 
    End Sub

End Class
```

Mis preguntas son:

1. La persona que va a ejecutar esta "aplicación", debe tener instalado Python...???
2. Se incluiur el script (código fuente) "prueba.py" en la distribución...???

Muchas Gracias.